# Grouping results and filtering duplicates by the row's date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that gets all the records grouped by `code` and the rows that are duplicated take the one with the most recent date.

```
+----------+---------+-------------+
| code     | name    | date        |
+----------+---------+-------------+
| a        | Mike    | 2009-01-05  |
| b        | Jones   | 2010-02-06  |
| b        | Who     | 2009-01-05  |
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

expected result:

```
+----------+---------+-------------+
| code     | name    | date        |
+----------+---------+-------------+
| a        | Mike    | 2009-01-05  |
| b        | Jones   | 2010-02-06  |
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

I've gotten this far:

```
SELECT code, name, date
FROM table
GROUP BY code
```

I'm not sure how to aggregate a column based on another column's value.

Comment: Duplicate of [Select most recent row by some other column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164918/select-most-recent-row-by-some-other-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have other columns that you're not aggregating (name) but are eliminating rows based on the date column (latest record only), using GROUP BY is not ideal.

You can use windowing functions to find the specific record based on the grouping (code) and return only those records.

Example:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT code
    , name
    , date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date DESC) AS [RowNumber]
  FROM Records
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

You can see a working example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a30db1c6bdbcf54f5ea666a4514d1d80). Basically it is using a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to assign a row number to each row within the code groups in a date descending order. This means you can simply select each row where the ROW_NUMBER value is 1.

Comment: I really like using this CTE approach to determine duplicates and rank by newest/oldest.  You can't use ORDER BY in a CTE, but ROW_Number() exposes and filters the record(s) to select in a subsequent SQL clause. (ie, non-original dupes = RowNumber > 1)

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions this can be done with a subquery. Note duplicates can occur if code and date are the same.

```
SELECT t.code, t.name, t.`date`
FROM table t
JOIN (
  SELECT code, MIN(`date`) as `date`
  FROM table
  GROUP BY code) AS m
  ON c.code=m.code AND c.`date`=m.`date`
```